# Error when creating PDA: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete

Tags: anchor, pda, anchor-test

Following error occurs when I try to run `anchor test`:

```
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete
      at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4819:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at Connection.sendRawTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4778:20)
      at sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:288:21)
      at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:148:14)
      at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16)
```

Here is the program code:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("57GYguBdvQKBbRsARLpAVFmC2XvPNMa3dPP9qHhZvkoE");

#[program]
pub mod house {
    use super::*;

    pub fn init_house(ctx: Context<InitHouse>, payout_amount: u8) -> Result<()> {
        InitHouse::initialise_house(ctx, payout_amount)
    }
}

impl InitHouse<'_>  {
    pub fn initialise_house(ctx: Context<Self>, fee_amount: u8) -> Result<()> {
        let vault = &mut ctx.accounts.vault;
        // vault.fee_vault = *ctx.accounts.fee_vault.to_account_info().key;
        vault.fee_amount = fee_amount;
        vault.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("house-vault").unwrap();

        Ok(())
    }
}


#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitHouse<'info> {
    // space: 8 discriminator + 32 house vault account + 32 fee vault
    // + 1 fee amount + 6 * 1  bet amounts + 1 bump
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = user,
        space = 8 + 32 + 32 + 1 + 6 + 1,
        seeds = [
            b"house-vault".as_ref(),
            user.key().as_ref()
        ],
        bump
    )]
    pub vault: Account<'info, HouseState>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct HouseState {
    pub house_vault: Pubkey,
    pub fee_vault: Pubkey,
    pub fee_amount: u8,
    pub bet_amounts: [u8; 6],
    pub bump: u8,
}
```

Here is the test script:

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { web3 } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { Program } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { CoinFlip } from "../target/types/coin_flip";

// const SOLANA_URL = 'https://api.devnet.solana.com';
const SOLANA_URL = 'http://localhost:8899';


describe("coin-flip", () => {
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());

  const program = anchor.workspace.CoinFlip as Program<CoinFlip>;
  const programOwner = (anchor.getProvider().wallet as AnchorWallet).payer;


  it("Init house", async () => {
     const [houseVaultPDA, _] = await web3.PublicKey
        .findProgramAddress(
          [
            Buffer.from("house-vault"),
            programOwner.publicKey.toBuffer()
          ],
          program.programId
        );
     console.log('House Vault PDA: ', houseVaultPDA.toString());

      await program.methods
           .initHouse(new anchor.BN(95))
           .accounts({
               user: programOwner.publicKey,
               vault: houseVaultPDA
           })
           .rpc();
    });
});
```

I was trying to solve this error by myself but with no luck. I know the Instruction 0 is `SystemProgram.CreateAccount`, and checked that `programOwner` has enough SOL to create a PDA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
vault.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("house-vault").unwrap();
```

You have to use the name of the account, not the seed to get the bump. So the correct code in your case will be:

```
vault.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("vault").unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your code a little bit. There seemed to be a problem with: `vault.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("house-vault").unwrap();`. It seems this is where it was failing. Here is the refactored code:

lib.rs:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("GNHuocp4uyUSUcQiS854jpubRJqQmVLYqZW4RMfH472o");

#[program]
pub mod house {
    use super::*;

    pub fn init_house(ctx: Context<InitHouse>, payout_amount: u64, base_bump: u8) -> Result<()> {
        InitHouse::initialise_house(ctx, payout_amount, base_bump)
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitHouse<'info> {
    // space: 8 discriminator + 32 house vault account + 32 fee vault
    // + 1 fee amount + 6 * 1  bet amounts + 1 bump
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = user,
        space = 8 + 32 + 32 + 1 + 6 + 8,
        seeds = [
            b"house-vault".as_ref(),
            user.key().as_ref()
        ],
        bump
    )]
    pub vault: Account<'info, HouseState>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

impl InitHouse<'_>  {
    pub fn initialise_house(ctx: Context<Self>, fee_amount: u64, base_bump: u8) -> Result<()> {
        let vault = &mut ctx.accounts.vault;
        // // vault.fee_vault = *ctx.accounts.fee_vault.to_account_info().key;
        vault.fee_amount = fee_amount;
        //vault.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("house-vault").unwrap();
        vault.bump = base_bump;

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[account]
pub struct HouseState {
    pub house_vault: Pubkey,
    pub fee_vault: Pubkey,
    pub fee_amount: u64,
    pub bet_amounts: [u8; 6],
    pub bump: u8,
}
```

And here is the test file:

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { web3 } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { Program } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { House } from "../target/types/house";
import { utf8 } from "@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/utils/bytes";
import { BN } from "bn.js";

// const SOLANA_URL = 'https://api.devnet.solana.com';
const SOLANA_URL = 'http://localhost:8899';

describe("coin-flip", () => {
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());
  const program = anchor.workspace.House as Program<House>;

  // const programOwner = (anchor.getProvider().wallet as AnchorWallet).payer;
  const programOwner = anchor.AnchorProvider.local().wallet.publicKey;


  it("Init house", async () => {
    const [houseVaultPDA, baseBump] = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [utf8.encode("house-vault"), programOwner.toBuffer()],
      program.programId
    );
    let bn = new BN(95, undefined, "le");
    console.log('House Vault PDA: ', houseVaultPDA.toString());
    console.log(typeof bn);
    await program.methods
      .initHouse(new BN(95), baseBump)
      .accounts({
        user: programOwner,
        vault: houseVaultPDA
      }).rpc();
  });
});
```

Also notice I have changed fee amount from u8 to u64. If you need to use u8 - you should not have to use BN because BN returns an array of bytes and u8 will expect a single byte only.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solved the problem. What is preferable way to calculate bump: on client side or in program?

Comment: I think when generating new bump - program is better,